# Multiple masks in adobe premiere and RAM

Tags: premiere, mask

I am editing a video clip of 5 minutes length. I am using multiple masks on it to blurry the face of a subject. I got to a point in which I cannot keep working because my RAM (8GB) it's getting saturated and I believe it is because I am using so many masks (12 masks). Is there a way of merging them all together or solving this problem?

Comment: When you say your RAM is getting 'saturated', what is actually happening? What are the symptoms?

Comment: I cannot keep working because everything starts working very slow. A lot of lag while working on the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd second what Ham the Epic said. I use 128 GB of Ram and AE and PPro eats it up especially when there are lots of layers with masks or effects.

Your only option to work around this would be to do the painful process of Masking your source with 1 layer; Render the Output Uncompressed, Import, Add 2nd Mask, and repeat.

This way you're only working with 1 mask at a a time.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly combining them wouldn't help that much. The problem is you need more memory. I have 64gb for AE and I still use all of it at times. I would say a base line is 16-32gb. I could easily use 128gb though.